# PostgreSQL: select results from many rows, roll up results and return a single row

Tags: postgresql, select

The Table in PostgreSQL 10 is created with:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Table"(
    "ID" serial,
    "Epoch" smallint,
    "Unit" smallint,
    "Value" double precision
);
```

and it stores readings from two measurements units.

Typically, both units should measure and produce indications parallely, so for the same time (called here: Epoch) two rows should be inserted.

However there are also moments that not all expected two readings are provided for a single Epoch, as it is presented on the example below (Epoch=30 and Epoch=40):

```
 Epoch | Unit | Value 
-------+------+-------
    10 |    1 |   1.1
    10 |    2 |   1.2
    20 |    1 |   2.1
    20 |    2 |   2.2
    30 |    1 |   3.1
    40 |    2 |   4.2
    50 |    1 |   5.1
    50 |    2 |   5.2
(8 rows)
```

I have a problem with a query building which do following:

1. Check if rows for Unit=1 and Unit=2 are present for the same Epoch
2. Return result for each Epoch for both measurement units in a single row, like here:

   ```
   Epoch ; Value_Unit1 ; Value_Unit2
   ```

Rows without indications coming from both units should be excluded from results.

I am looking for a solution giving (for provided example) the exact result as follow:

```
10 ; 1.1 ; 1.2

20 ; 2.1 ; 2.2

50 ; 5.1 ; 5.2
```

Many examples here deal with a very similiar issues but they don't allow me finding right answer for my specific problem or ... I can't understand tips suggested there.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table with itself giving both occurrences different aliases:

```
SELECT
    T1."Epoch",
    T1."Value" AS Value_Unit1,
    T2."Value" AS Value_Unit2
FROM
    public."Table" AS T1
    JOIN public."Table" AS T2
    USING("Epoch")
WHERE
    T1."Unit" = 1 AND
    T2."Unit" = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. Unfortunatelly, I receive error 42703, ERROR: column "epoch" specified in USING clause does not exist in left table. Could you please improve your answer ?

Comment: @frankie Right, all column names should be quoted. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Perfect ! Works as expected, however I had to add quotation marks also for "Unit" and "Value". Thank you very much!

Comment: @frankie I'm glad I could help. As a new user, please take a while to read [Help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) including [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Done. But my gathered so far reputation level does not allow for changing publicly displayed post score. Sorry :)